# probability of a word count given polarity

Tags: python, dictionary, count, probability

I have 2 dictionaries: counts['pos'] (words in positive tweets and their numbers) and counts['neg'] (same for negative tweets). The question asks me to define a function which gives me P(word|polarity). My code actually works, but does not give me the desired answer.

```
possum=sum(counts['pos'].values())
negsum=sum(counts['neg'].values())
def get_word_prob(counts, word, polarity):
    """ 
    calculates the probability of a word given a polarity 

    Parameters:
    counts (dict): the dictionaries 'pos' and 'neg' which count word occurances
    word (str): the word you want to get the probability for
    polarity (str): wither 'pos' or 'neg'

    Returns:
    probability (float):  the probability of a word given a polarity 

    """
    # Your code goes here
    if word not in counts[polarity]:
      return 0    
    if word in counts['pos']:
            probability = counts['pos'][word] / possum
    if word in counts['neg']:
            probability = counts['neg'][word] / negsum


     #Divide the count of the given word by the total sum

    return probability # P(word|polarity)
print(get_word_prob(counts, "great", "pos")) # should print 0.00255902660421998
print(get_word_prob(counts, "glad", "neg")) # should print 0.00012164155275442091
print(get_word_prob(counts, "wugs", "neg")) # should print 0
```

keep in mind that I can only change this section:

```
if word not in counts[polarity]:
      return 0    
    if word in counts['pos']:
            probability = counts['pos'][word] / possum
    if word in counts['neg']:
            probability = counts['neg'][word] / negsum
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of an input, the current output, and the expected output?

Comment: print(get_word_prob(counts, "great", "pos")) # should print 0.00255902660421998
print(get_word_prob(counts, "glad", "neg")) # should print 0.00012164155275442091
print(get_word_prob(counts, "wugs", "neg")) # should print 0

these are the inputs if that's what you meant. desired outputs are after #. my results are basically some different values.

Comment: Barring incorrect indentation, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the construction of the code. You might want to check if your `possum`, `negsum` values match the expected values in the first place.